# change solaris network timeout

Tags: windows, unix, tcp, solaris

I need to have as quick timeout as I get (connection failed) on windows.  but on solaris its much longer, how can I make it shorten? (I'm trying to connect on purpose to a machine that does not exist to simulate a machine is down).

When I'm performing this **on windows --> timeout --> good**

> D:>telnet 192.168.23.21 222
>
> Connecting To 192.168.23.21...Could not open connection to the host, on port 23:
>
> Connect failed
>
> D:>

on windows (the target ip does not exist)
then in about 15 seconds the command terminates.

However when I perform this from a **solaris --> very long timeout --> not good for my legacy code** machine like this:

> myuser@mycomp:~$ telnet 192.168.23.21 222
>
> Trying 192.168.23.21...

Then the process does not terminate

and this has major implications for me because i'm migrating an app from windows to solaris, and I must be able to have this timeout (in legacy code which I cannot update), so I need at the OS level to control this timeout to be as short as is currently in windows.  **How can I change this timeout in my solaris OS then? to be short, just as I havbe it on windows**

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you absolutely have to do this systemwide, there's a TCP driver parameter `tcp_ip_abort_cinterval` that can be modified:

> tcp_ip_abort_cinterval - This is the
>   amount of time that a connection is
>           allowed to stay in a half open state.  This is 180,000
>           (3 minutes) by default.  You can change this to 25,000
>           if you want (25 seconds).  Please note that by changing this
>           you may find that SLIP/PPP users may have problems conacting
>           your site.
>
> To view your current setting:
>
> /usr/sbin/ndd /dev/tcp
>   tcp_ip_abort_cinterval
>
> To change the setting:
>
> /usr/sbin/ndd -set /dev/tcp
>   tcp_ip_abort_cinterval 25000

Comment: thanks, i'm checking this.  What are the implications on OS if i change this timeout to 60 seconds? as for my personal "app server" I feel safe on changing this, but I just fear will this have some bad implications on my general solaris OS? bad effect for 60 sec timeout on its behaviour as its default seems to be longer.  Thanks

Comment: tcp tcp_ip_abort_cinterval Hi I update this variable and got these results: 30sec --> 50 sec
10 sec --> 25 sec
20 sec --> 24 sec
40 sec --> 52 sec  which means for 30sec set of this param my timeout was 50 sec for 10 sec my timeout was 25 sec... how come its not exact?

Comment: @Jason: Good question...maybe some of the wait is happening outside the TCP/IP connect() call.  I'd recommend using a tool like Wireshark to see exactly what's going on at the packet level -- perhaps the OS is trying to do a reverse DNS lookup or something similar, which wouldn't be affected by tcp_ip_abort_cinterval.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could set the socket option [`SO_SNDTIMEO`](http://portabilityblog.com/blog/archives/10-SO_SNDTIMEO-and-SO_RCVTIMEO.html) -- that link reports Solaris doesn't respect that option, but you might be lucky and they've fixed it by now. :)

If the socket option doesn't work, you could always set an `alarm(2)` for some point in the future and interrupt your `connect(2)` call. It feels pretty gross, but it is an option.

Another option is to switch to non-blocking socket operations and *poll* at some point in the future if the `connect(2)` operation succeeded or not. You could see a timeout to `select(2)` and discover if it has errored or is readable/writable. (See also the `EINPROGRESS` bit in `connect(2)`.)

Comment: It sounds like Jason isn't allowed to change that part of the code (although I agree that that would probably be preferable to changing a systemwide setting that may have unexpected consequences).

Comment: @Jim Lewis, I figured he had to change _some_ amount of code to port from Windows to Solaris, he was just interested in not having to re-architect the whole thing. But if the machine is going to be dedicated to his program, your solution looks perfect for him. :)